# cffile is overwriting existing file

Tags: coldfusion, cffile

The nameconflict attribute doesn't seem well documented, so maybe I'm using it wrong. But if I write a file (binary data) using the following code, it's overwriting the existing file of the same name.

```
<cffile action="write" file="/path/#data.name#" output="#d#" nameconflict="MakeUnique" mode="775">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nameconflict="MakeUnique"`  only works for `<cffile action="upload"`.

Overwriting the file is default behavior for `<cffile action="write"`

Unless exact file names are not needed for display purpose it is better approach to use a unique ID as the filename to make sure we do not overwrite files.

```
<cfset newFile = '/path/' & CreateUUID() & '.' & ListLast(data.name, '.')>
<cffile action="write" file="#newFile#" output="#d#" mode="775">
```

**Note:** For use cases where we need to have a custom file name for view purposes, its better to save that original file name in the database and keep the filename in the filesystem in separate column.

Comment: IMO, still a good idea even if you do need the original name. Save the original name in the database too, and use it with cfheader when downloading, etc

Comment: I probably will store the original filename, at least to have it displayed that way to the user.